# Is the difference of two i.i.d. random variables symmetric around $0$?

Tags: random-variables, independence

Let $X, Y$ be i.i.d. random variables. Is $\mathbb{P}(X \le Y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \le X)$?

This looks "obvious" to me. I can't think of a reason why this should not be true. But how can I prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are iid then $(X,Y)$ has the same joint distribution as $(Y,X)$. Consequently $X-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y-X$. Since $X-Y$ has the same distribution as its opposite, this means that $X-Y$ is symmetric.

Independence is necessary: For example if the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the three pairs $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(2,0)$ then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but the distribution of $Y-X$ is not symmetric about $0$: It has mass $\frac23$ on the point $1$ and mass $\frac13$ on the point $-2$.