# PDF of difference of two i.i.d. random variables: maximum at $0$ and decreasing to the right of $0$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X, Y$ be two i.i.d. random variables with an arbitrary distribution. As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831259/is-the-difference-of-two-i-i-d-random-variables-symmetric-around-0), the distribution of their difference $X-Y$ is symmetric around $0$.

What I am wondering:

- Does this distribution (probability density function) also necessarily have its maximum at $0$?
- Is it necessarily monotone decreasing (increasing) to the right (left) of $0$?

Intuitively, it feels correct (difference between two variables with the same distribution should be close to zero, with larger values less likely), but I only found proofs for specific distributions.

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes: in the discrete case, simply note that, by Cauchy-Schwarz, for every $y$, $$P(X-Y=y)^2=\left(\sum_xp(x)p(x-y)\right)^2\leqslant\sum_xp(x)^2\sum_xp(x-y)^2=P(X-Y=0)^2$$ The answer to the second question is no, as shows the case when $X=Z+B$ with $Z$ standard normal and $B$ is Bernoulli uniform on $\{-b,+b\}$ for some large $b$ and independent of $Z$.

Comment: Consider generating $X$ (in R syntax) as `(rbinom(n, 1, 1/2)*2-1) * rnorm(n, 3, 1)` - that is, a Normal(3, 1) multiplied by 1 or -1 with the two sign choices equally likely.  Then a quick simulation shows that the PDF is not monotone decreasing to the right of zero - values of $X - Y$ near 6 are much more likely than those near 3. (This is essentially a special case of Did's answer but I had already started writing this when that answer appeared.)

Comment: @Did Thanks! I'm a bit slow on this and do not quite get the last equality in you equation. Where did the $y$ go?

Comment: Of course we know that, for every integer $y$, $$\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}p(x-y)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}p(x)$$ don't we?

Comment: @Did Oh ok, thanks :) Do you want to turn this into an answer so I can accept it?